# English translation of Jquery default messages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am translating one project to my own language, but I can't find where I should translate the buttons "Yes", "No" and "Cancel" on the jquery

For example, this line creates a pop up when the user wants to logout:

```
function logout(){
    jQueryConfirmWithTitle('Are you sure you want to logout?', 'Confirm logout',function() {logoff(false);});
};

function logoff(timeOut) {
    $('#logoffTimeout').val(timeOut ? 'true' : 'false');
    $('#logoffForm').submit();
};
```

Where should I go to translate those standard string messages of jquery?

Edit:
As @MikeC pointed, this is not a jquery function as I thought it was, so I looked more deep into this function and found where it was declared.

```
function jQueryConfirmWithTitle(confirmText, titleText, callbackOnYes) {
    jQueryConfirmWithYesNoCallback(confirmText, titleText, callbackOnYes, function() {});
}

function jQueryConfirmWithYesNoCallback(confirmText, titleText, callbackOnYes, callbackOnNo) {
    var dlgConfirm = $('#dlgConfirm');
    dlgConfirm.empty().html('<p style="font-size: 1.0em;">'+confirmText+'</p>');
    dlgConfirm.dialog({
        modal: true,
        title: titleText,
        buttons: {
            Yes: function() {
                $( this ).dialog("close");
                callbackOnYes();
            },
            No: function() {
                $( this ).dialog("close");
                callbackOnNo();
            }
        },
        open: function() { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); }
    });
}
```

Comment: `jQueryConfirmWithTitle` is a non-standard jQuery function. Meaning, we have no way of determining where that text is set.

Comment: What library or method are you using to create the pop up? Because as @Mike comments this is not a jQuery function.

Comment: How do you translate 'Are you sure you want to logout?'? Do you have some hash like tr = {'hu':{'Are you sure you want to logout?':'Biztos, hogy ki akarsz lépni?'}}? I guess you do. 1st translate the jquery strings you need the same way. Then show us that part of the code (add to the question).

Answer (score -1):

You can use one of the plugins, for example: https://github.com/wikimedia/jquery.i18n or https://github.com/recurser/jquery-i18n or https://github.com/coderifous/jquery-localize.

You'll need to provide the strings in jsons for each language.